# Kotlin index is not out of bounds using arraylist

Tags: java, kotlin

I created an arraylist with 4 items

```
val myList = arrayListOf("Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4")
```

Then I printed a random item from myList

```
val randomNum = Random()
val randomItem = randomNum.nextInt(myList.count())
println(myList[randomItem])
```

Shouldn't this fail? Once randomItem is equal to 4? Ideally what I'm asking is that randomItem is returning an int from 0-4, correct? But the arraylist index is only 0-3. Should I do -1 to randomItem? I'm just confused because the program isn't throwing an error.

Comment: Don't be sorry. You learn. But next times, think of javadoc. It contains most important things.

Answer (score 4):

See the API here [Random.nextInt(int bound)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-)

> public int nextInt(int bound)
>
> Returns a pseudorandom, **uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)**, drawn from this random number generator's sequence. The general contract of nextInt is that one int value in the specified range is pseudorandomly generated and returned. All bound possible int values are produced with (approximately) equal probability.
>
> **Parameters**:
>   bound - the upper bound (**exclusive**). Must be positive.
>
> **Returns**:
>   the next pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between zero (inclusive) and bound (exclusive) from this random number generator's sequence

So in your case, you get 0, 1, 2 or 3

Comment: my apologies, i'm obviously not thinking today

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) explains it pretty well:

> `int nextInt(int bound)`
>
> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value **(exclusive)**, drawn from this random number generator's sequence.